# Right to left typing in text box?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, maskedtextbox

I have a Currency `Textbox` with a mask.
Mask is shown in `textbox` as `--------.--`

So user types in digits over the mask.

Now customer says he does not want to type in letter from left to right.
He wants to type from right to left.

Similar to what we have in calculator.

Now I tried changing the `textbox`'s `righttoleft` property but that does not help my cause.

In the end I am stuck with handling the key event to manually change the position.
I am able to change the position but getting stuck completing the logic.

Here's how my code looks like :

```
 void Textbx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {


        String temp = T.Text;
        string temp2 = T.Text;

        int CursorIndex = T.SelectionStart - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i <= CursorIndex; i++)
        {
            if (i == 7)
            {

                temp2 = temp2.Insert(i, temp[i + 2].ToString());
                temp2 = temp2.Remove(i, 2);

                //i = i + 2;
            }
            else if (CursorIndex == i)
            {
                temp2 = temp2.Remove(i, 1);
                temp2 = temp2.Insert(i, temp[i + 1].ToString());
            }

            else
            {
                //   T.Text = T.Text.Insert(i + 1, "_");

                temp2 = temp2.Insert(i, temp[i + 1].ToString());
                temp2 = temp2.Remove(i + 1, 1);

            }

        }
        T.Text = temp2;
        // T.Text = T.Text.Insert(CursorIndex-1, temp[CursorIndex].ToString());
        if (CursorIndex != -1)
            T.SelectionStart = CursorIndex - 1;


    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? If not how should I go about completing the logic?

Answer (score 4):

There is a property for that in the textbox:

```
T.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes
```

Comment: Hi tried that but when I do that mask that I have changes to "--.--------" from "--------.--". So here it does the same thing as before that is typing from digit places towards decimal places. I want to let user type from decimal then towards unit,tens and so on. For typing 6.95. cursor will be at the right and user will just type 695 and it will shown as 6.95.

Answer (score 2):

I have written this code for you; please try it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string mychar = "000000";
        string mtxt;
        int mypos = 6;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maskedTextBox1.Text = mychar;
    }

    private void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            mtxt = mtxt + e.KeyChar;
            mypos--;
            mychar = mychar.Remove(mypos, mtxt.Length);
            mychar = mychar.Insert(mypos, mtxt);
            maskedTextBox1.Text = mychar;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using a maskedTextBox.

set TextMaskFormat Property = IncludePrompt

```
    private void maskedTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart = maskedTextBox1.Mask.Length + 1;
    }

    private void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar != (char) Keys.Back)
        {
            String a = maskedTextBox1.Text + e.KeyChar;
            maskedTextBox1.Text = a.Substring(1, a.Length - 1);
            maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart = maskedTextBox1.Mask.Length + 1;
        }
    }

    private void maskedTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        {
            maskedTextBox1.Text = "_" + maskedTextBox1.Text;
            maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart = maskedTextBox1.Mask.Length + 1;
        } 
    }
```